# Upload file (> 4MB) to OneDrive using Graph API

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I am trying to upload files to OneDrive using Graph API. The below code works fine when I upload files with size lesser than 4MB but it shows an error when I try to upload files more than 4 MB. I went through [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) but still, I am not sure how can I get this work.

Below is my working code for files less than 4MB.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + $"/drives/{driveID}/items/{folderId}:/{originalFileName}:/content";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());

    byte[] sContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var content = new ByteArrayContent(sContents);

    var response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

Please help

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We need to split the byte array by length (i.e. 4MB) and pass them to the OneDrive API. The working version is below:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0" + $"/drives/{driveID}/items/{folderId}:/{originalFileName}:/createUploadSession";
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + GetAccessToken());

    var sessionResponse = client.PostAsync(apiUrl, null).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

    byte[] sContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
    var uploadSession = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UploadSessionResponse>(sessionResponse);
    string response = UploadFileBySession(uploadSession.uploadUrl, sContents);
}
```

UploadFileBySession is as follows:

```
private string UploadFileBySession(string url, byte[] file)
{
    int fragSize = 1024 * 1024 * 4;
    var arrayBatches = ByteArrayIntoBatches(file, fragSize);
    int start = 0;
    string response = "";

    foreach (var byteArray in arrayBatches)
    {
        int byteArrayLength = byteArray.Length;
        var contentRange = " bytes " + start + "-" + (start + (byteArrayLength - 1)) + "/" + file.Length;

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(byteArray);
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", byteArrayLength.ToString());
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", contentRange);

            response = client.PutAsync(url, content).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        }

        start = start + byteArrayLength;
    }
    return response;
}

internal IEnumerable<byte[]> ByteArrayIntoBatches(byte[] bArray, int intBufforLengt)
{
    int bArrayLenght = bArray.Length;
    byte[] bReturn = null;

    int i = 0;
    for (; bArrayLenght > (i + 1) * intBufforLengt; i++)
    {
        bReturn = new byte[intBufforLengt];
        Array.Copy(bArray, i * intBufforLengt, bReturn, 0, intBufforLengt);
        yield return bReturn;
    }

    int intBufforLeft = bArrayLenght - i * intBufforLengt;
    if (intBufforLeft > 0)
    {
        bReturn = new byte[intBufforLeft];
        Array.Copy(bArray, i * intBufforLengt, bReturn, 0, intBufforLeft);
        yield return bReturn;
    }
}
```

UploadSessionResponse class file to deserialize JSON response when you create upload session

```
public class UploadSessionResponse
{
    public string odatacontext { get; set; }
    public DateTime expirationDateTime { get; set; }
    public string[] nextExpectedRanges { get; set; }
    public string uploadUrl { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: what is .ToProperString()? I cannot find it on Google. What lib is it in?

Comment: @BeauD'Amore It is an extension created within my application. I have changed it to "ToString()"

Answer (score 6):

For files bigger then 4MB you need to [create an uploadSession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0) that you POST to this URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/{item-path}:/createUploadSession
```

Pass an array of items,

```
{
  "item": {
    "@odata.type": "microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties",
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "rename",
    "name": "largefile.dat"
  }
}
```

*I use `"@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior": "overwrite"`, instead of `rename`.*

The response will provide an upload url to upload the file in batches

```
{
  "uploadUrl": "https://sn3302.up.1drv.com/up/fe6987415ace7X4e1eF866337",
  "expirationDateTime": "2015-01-29T09:21:55.523Z"
}
```

I don't have a c# example but here's a PHP one:

```php
$url = $result['uploadUrl'];
$fragSize = 1024*1024*4;
$file = file_get_contents($source);
$fileSize = strlen($file);
$numFragments = ceil($fileSize / $fragSize);
$bytesRemaining = $fileSize;
$i = 0;
$response = null;

while ($i < $numFragments) {
    $chunkSize = $numBytes = $fragSize;
    $start = $i * $fragSize;
    $end = $i * $fragSize + $chunkSize - 1;
    $offset = $i * $fragSize;

    if ($bytesRemaining < $chunkSize) {
        $chunkSize = $numBytes = $bytesRemaining;
        $end = $fileSize - 1;
    }

    if ($stream = fopen($source, 'r')) {
        // get contents using offset
        $data = stream_get_contents($stream, $chunkSize, $offset);
        fclose($stream);
    }

    $contentRange = " bytes " . $start . "-" . $end . "/" . $fileSize;
    $headers = array(
        "Content-Length: $numBytes",
        "Content-Range: $contentRange"
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $server_output = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $bytesRemaining = $bytesRemaining - $chunkSize;
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I am now successful in uploading files with size more than 4MB. I will add C# version now.